# Missing document history move file to record center SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, records-center

I have a document library with some documents set. I created a site collection with record center as template. I configured everything so when I press "Move to other location" and click on the Location created by my administrator, the document set with all the files are transfered to the records center without any problem. The only problem is that all my documents lose their history in the records center. Why? And how to keep it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When documents are passed to Record Centre, versioning is lost. Perhaps a custom solution can be built to allow versioning.

see

https://andrewwarland.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/sharepoint-2010-send-to-records-center-centre/